# How can I ensure padding works on a grid item with limited height?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a simple grid layout, that has a limited height and scrolls.

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  padding: 30px;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    one
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    two
  </div>
</div>
```

The padding is being applied at the top, left and right of the grid:

[image]

But when I scroll down, the padding on the bottom isn't applied:

[image]

If I remove the `max-height` the padding at the bottom is now applied:

[image]

**Why isn't the bottom padding being used? How can I ensure padding works on a grid item with limited height?**

Comment: margin to the last item?

Comment: @TemaniAfif doesn't work - see https://jsfiddle.net/ugh65oqa/5/ - the margin will go below the grid. Also per the question I'd like to know /why/ the bottom isn't being used rather than to hack around the issue.

Comment: We've run into the exact same issue and decided to live with it. If I had to guess it's the overflow detection algorithm trying to fit in best possible and considering an eventual `padding-bottom` not worthwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clarity around overflow and padding is a [current issue in the CSS spec](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/129) and the behavior may differ based on each case.

Until the spec is clarified or browsers change their behavior, a workaround for your use case is to add an empty element at the end (since your padding is equal to the gap).

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  padding: 30px;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.outer::after {
  content:"";
  height:0.1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    one
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    two
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a workaround, but for dynamic layouts this is hardly an option, and also does not address OP's question as of why does this happen in the first place.

Comment: @mikemaccana when I will find the related question I will close as duplicate. Actually I am not able to find it as this a known behavior and you need to do something to overcome it (you call it a workaround but I call it a solution)

Comment: @connexo check this: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/129

Comment: @TemaniAfif Isn't it amazing that this issue has basically been dragged out for 9 years now? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748518

Comment: @connexo it's not the only issue having such situation. A lot of issue/bug/strange behavior are alive since too long and we have to live with them using *workarounds*

Comment: That's unfortunately true, but too many common things in grid layout will break when using this workaround.

Comment: @mikemaccana that's not the Spec. It's a discussion around the issue to highlight that there is no clear behavior around this and until a consensus is found, we have to consider *workarounds*

Comment: @connexo it's only for this particular case. It's not a generic workaround. we need to find something else for another configuration

Comment: @TemaniAfif if you modify your answer to primarily point to https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/129 and then add the workaround I'd upvote it and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I couldn't hold back and added a salty comment. https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/129#issuecomment-814839174

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the inner content with a div/container and give the container the grid display, in that case the padding will be applied on that div.

```
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.outer-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  padding: 30px;
  grid-gap: 30px;
}

.inner {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="outer-content">
       <div class="inner">one</div>
       <div class="inner">Two</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but similar to the other answer this is a workaround rather than a solution, and omits an explanation why the border at the bottom is being removed.